# Polygonal Venn diagrams

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Suppose that the interiors of $n$ $m$-sided planar simple closed polygons generate a $\sigma$-algebra $A$.

How many atoms can $A$ possess, at the most?

Failing an exact answer, how about good bounds?

Comment: No idea, but my colleague, Frank Ruskey has done a lot of work on Venn diagrams with various conditions. Maybe look at some of his work?

Comment: Why is this a $\sigma$-algebra? I mean as there are only finitely many polygons, this is the same as the algebra generated by them, right?

Comment: Meanwhile, see the awesome symmetrical polygonal Venn diagrams of Rusky, Savage and Wagon in their AMS Notices cover article here: http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/ea-wagon.pdf#page=8.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want a bound on the primal shatter function of $m$-gons. For a little intro to the notion, see e.g., http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4850/2009sp/Scribe%20Notes/Lecture%2034%20Monday%20April%2013.pdf

or Matousek's book: http://books.google.hu/books?id=QS6vnl8WlnQC&pg=PA984&lpg=PA984&dq=shatter+func+matousek&source=bl&ots=4BECUUrDge&sig=lftBHslLFq_s0bJVQBCW9Si1jPA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JuyzU7aSOIfY7AaTrYDwCw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=shatter%20func%20matousek&f=false

It is not hard to prove that the VC-dimension of convex $m$-gons is $2m+1$, so the answer to your question would be about $n^{2m+1}$.